# Robust to solve a given cubic equation: Given roots are complex

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

Devise the algorithm to find the roots of cubic equation: $7x^3 + 11x^2 + 5x-2=0$.

This question was asked in one of the quant finance interviews.

Comment: numerical approximation or exact answer? The analytic solutions isn't too pretty

Comment: Lets start with numerical approximation. How would you approach analytically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerically, Newton's method should work - We start with a guess at the solution. Let's just let $x_0 = 1$ 
We now let our next guess, $x_1$, be $x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$ (the derivative is easily calculated here with the power rule if you know any calculus... if you don't, the answer is $ 5 + 22 x + 21 x^2$) 
$$x_1 = x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)} = 1-\frac{21}{48} = \frac{27}{48}$$
$$x_2 = x_1-\frac{f(x_1)}{f'(x_1)} = \frac{27}{48}- \frac{22687}{98384} = \frac{16327}{49192}$$
Continuing this, we get that $x_8 \approx 0.2460098817120613$ which is only off by $\approx 4.4227 × 10^{-17}$

If you want an analytic solution, we first try the Rational Roots Theorem.
Using the Rational Roots Theorem, we quickly find that any solutions will be of the form $\pm \frac{1,2}{1,7} = \{1,\frac 17, 2,\frac 27\}$
Plugging in and checking shows that no solutions exist, so we are forced to apply the cubic formula. It's not a super fun formula to use, but can be found online easily.

Comment: Note that this will find the real root.  The other two roots are not real, and Newton's method as explained above will never find them.  In general, there are algorithms like in the link below, but in this case, since we've found the real root $x_r$, we can divide the polynomial by $(x-x_r)$ to get a quadratic and use the quadratic formula.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_algorithm

Comment: You can use Newton-Raphson with a complex initial guess and it will be able to find complex roots, but as usual the guess must be "good" or N-R might oscillate or exhibit chaotic behavior. It is certainly more advisable to use a more robust root-finding algorithm, however.